# How does a nested class inherit from a container class?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I came across the follow code while looking at something else in a codebase at work today, and I cannot even figure out how such a thing works.  Can someone explain to me how this is possible?

```
class Outer {
    void MethodOne(); // Non-virtual
    // more non-virtual methods
    public class InnerFoo : Outer { // HOW is this possible?
         void InnerMethodOne(); 
         // more methods on the derived class
    }
    public class InnerBar : Outer { // o_O
         // stuff
    }
}
```

I have no idea how the compiler parses this, let alone interprets such a class structure.

Comment: even it is possible, it may not be best practice and makes little sense.

Comment: Not really sure how to answer your question other than.. why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a compiler point of view this is fairly straightforward. The compiler outputs MSIL for two classes that inherit from `Outer`. Any code that attempts to reference `InnerBar` or `InnerFoo` outside of the namespace of `Outer` will result in a compile error.

In terms of the output byte code, this code is identical to the following

```
class Outer {
    void MethodOne();
    // more non-virtual methods
}

class InnerFoo : Outer {
    void InnerMethodOne(); 
    // more methods on the derived class
}

class InnerBar : Outer {
    // stuff
}
```

The relevant point to remember is that to the compiler, a class is just a class whether nested or not. The only difference between a nested class, and an ordinary class is how the compiler permits other classes to reference it.

Comment: Ahh, thanks.  I never use nested classes (never see a real reason too), so didn't realize that was how the compiler treated them.

Comment: They're very much worth your time - they can be extremely useful for preserving encapsulation, or when you need to avoid polluting an API namespace with various utility classes.